# Generating query for given table

Tags: sql

I have table

```
        id  year  month  day  
         1  2012    1     1
         2  2012    1     2
         3  2012    1     3
         4  2012    1     4
         5  2012    1     5
         6  2012    1     7
         7  2012    1     8
         8  2012    1     9
         9  2012    1     10
         10 2012    1     11
```

from the above table i want to generate the following output when count of id reaches the 
multiple of 5

```
          day_start day_end
             1         5   
             5         11
```

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please also post what RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in SQL Server. Using the `row_number` rather than the `id` field value will prevent errors if you delete rows and the sequence of ids is no longer complete.

**Note**: I'm basing this answer on the fact that you said the *"count of id*" reaches 5, and not *"the value of id"*. Which to me means **"every 5 records, regardless of the id value"**. If that's not the case, then leave a comment and I'll remove this answer, since Mark's will work fine.

```
select case when rownumber = 5 then 1 else rownumber - 5 end as day_start, day_end
from
(
    select row_number() over (order by id) as RowNumber, [day] as day_end
    from table1
) t
where rownumber % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the Day_start came from. This may give you an idea on how to tackle this problem.

```
SELECT id as day_start, day as day_end
FROM MyTable
WHERE mod(id, 5) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQL, try:

```
select min(coalesce(p.day,c.day)) day_start, max(c.day) day_end
from my_table c
left join my_table p on p.id = c.id-1
group by floor((c.id-1)/5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE id WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE id - 5 END AS day_start, day AS day_end
FROM [TableName]
WHERE id % 5 = 0
```